# Flume ElasticSearchSink does not consume all messages

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

I am using flume to process log lines to hdfs and log them into ElasticSearch using ElasticSearchSink.

Here is my configuration:

```
agent.channels.memory-channel.type = memory

agent.sources.tail-source.type = exec
agent.sources.tail-source.command = tail -4000 /home/cto/hs_err_pid11679.log
agent.sources.tail-source.channels = memory-channel

agent.sinks.log-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.log-sink.type = logger

#####INTERCEPTORS

agent.sources.tail-source.interceptors = timestampInterceptor
agent.sources.tail-source.interceptors.timestampInterceptor.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder

####SINK
# Setting the sink to HDFS
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/data/flume/%y-%m-%d/
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.inUsePrefix =.
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.rollSize = 10000000
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.idleTimeout = 10
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

agent.sinks.elastic-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchSink
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.hostNames = 127.0.0.1:9300
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.indexName = flume_index
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.indexType = logs_type
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.clusterName = elasticsearch
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.batchSize = 500
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.ttl = 5d
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDynamicSerializer


# Finally, activate.
agent.channels = memory-channel
agent.sources = tail-source
agent.sinks = log-sink hdfs-sink elastic-sink
```

The problem is that I only see 1-2 messages in elastic using kibana and lots of messages in the hdfs files.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Not sure what was the problem but I am wondering if this might be due to sending events using one channel to multiple sinks? [see here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flume-user/201306.mbox/%3C1371049495.4548.YahooMailNeo@web163903.mail.gq1.yahoo.com%3E) also learned that `agent.sinks.elastic-sink.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDynamicSerializer` should be dropped otherwise the timestamp field is created with the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to a bug in the Serializer.
if we drop the line:

```
agent.sinks.elastic-sink.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDynamicSerializer
```

the messages are consumed with no problem.
The problem is with the way the @timestamp field is created when using the serializer.